# Beautiful Soup 4 parsing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can i find all divs that have more than one parameters like this
this is under a 
td tag

```
<td id = "abcdef">
    <div class="12345" id="456" abc="789" def="1123" ghi="">
```

i tried

```
soup.find_all("div",{"class":"12345"})
```

and

```
soup.find_all("div",class_="12345")
```

both statements return empty.

**it doesn't matter what the other elements are i just want to compare for *class* parameter.**

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Your code works fine for me both ways.

Comment: so i am trying to webscrape from indeed is there anything i am leaving out.
this is the link:
 https://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=work+from+home&l=Mississauga%2C+ON 
i am inspecting, am i leaving any useful info out.
i am checking for business technical analyst(3 month contract) and inspecting it

Comment: It is your responsibility to produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you provide us with the exact code you're using to scrape, and the exact page your scraping from? That would help us a lot with figuring out what the issue might be. I tried to find elements in the link you provided which match your scraping example, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Sorry for all this I figured it out, so there was more than 1 TD. so I needed to find all and then find the relative div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
td = soup.find('td')
td.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "12345"})
```

Hope it helps